# Android apk installing both the activity with its default name and with its alias

Tags: android, android-studio

The main activity of my Android app, has a default name and an alias name that should be put to the app if the user chooses to. I've defined that on my AndroidManifest.xml in the following manner.

```
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.fgd.myapplication4.MainActivity4"
        android:label="mydefaultlabel"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:label="myaliaslabel"
        android:name=".MainActivity-Flavor-One"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity4"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>
</application>
```

But I've tried to build the apk and install it my phone and it installs either an icon with the name "mydefaultlabel" to access the app and another one with "myaliaslabel" to access it, which is not my desired behavior, on start I want it to just install the icon with "mydefaultlabel".

Any idea on what should I do to achieve this behavior?

PD: Trying to delete   and
, causes to not be able to run the app any longer, once I change the alias of the app with this code:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                            new ComponentName("com.example.alber.myapplication4", "com.example.alber.myapplication4.MainActivity-Flavor-One"),
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
                            new ComponentName("com.example.alber.myapplication4", "com.example.alber.myapplication4.MainActivity4"),
                            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I get the error that the app is not installed on my Android device.

It looks like, no matter what, the alias has to be defined with the launcher category to be able to change the application alias this way.

I see no way to change alias except in this way.

Is there something else that could be done?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting two **Main Activity** and **LAUNCHER**

```
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> //<--wrong
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> <--wrong
```

you need to add these lines only to your specific activity that implement your icon or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work, I'm editing my post to show the related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was actually easier than what I though.

In  activity-alias you just need to change android:enabled="true" to android:enabled="false", this way the alias will still be functional but won't show as a launcher for the first time.